# Do browsers localize the OK and Cancel buttons of the javascript confirm popup?

Tags: javascript, localization, confirm

In a multi-language web site, can I rely on the javascript `confirm` to translate the text of the Ok/Cancel buttons? If so, is it related to the browser or OS language setting?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The OK/Cancel button in Internet Explorer will obey the **Operating System** UI language settings.

The technical reason is that IE is using the `MessageBox` Win32 API call to display its Javascript dialog box. That API relies on the OS UI language and not the browser UI language, as it is owned by the OS.

As for 3rd party browsers, it really depends if they are using `MessageBox` or not to display their box. If they are, it will obey to the **Operating System** language, if not, it will obey to the **browser** UI language.

**EDIT:** Firefox and Chrome are not using `MessageBox` so technically they should be following the browser UI language settings, <strike>though I don't have a french install to test it on</strike>. **CONFIRMED**

---

If you must localize your buttons, your best bet would be a modal DHTML dialog.

Comment: ie: you could install the french-language firefox on an german-language windows xp.  Now what should confirm show?  +1

Comment: In IE6, at least, the languages dialog says "Menus and Dialogs are currently displayed in ...." at the bottom. It doesn't change based upon your browser's language, which supports this.

Comment: **@Joel:** A french install of Firefox will have its buttons localized in french no matter what the OS UI language is.

Answer (score 10):

My OS language is French and the OK and Cancel buttons are in french so the answer is : yes!

IE :

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Firefox :

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Chrome :

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Comment: What does your Firefox or Chrome do?

Comment: And your OS install is in french, this post doesn't really provide any insight on why they are localized.

Comment: While this is a very old answer, I thought it would be worthwhile letting you know that the linked images are all dead.