# Localization for javascript confirmation buttons

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, confirm

I am working with Confirm box in javascript.  For all browsers i found that when change the language of the browser, the confirmation button language in Confirm box doesn't change.  I tested on chrome, firefox by changing the language to french.  But the buttons label is not translated.  Label of "OK" and "Cancel" doesn't change to other language.

Please Note : I am trying to see the localized string on confirmation box.

Comment: Localization is not an inherent feature in browsers, JavaScript, or the HTML specification. In other words, you need to manage localization on your own (usually detecting language on the server side and emitting the appropriate strings in the resulting HTML). Are you doing something specific where this expectation is met? If so, provide more details so we can help.

Comment: I need to see the labels "OK" and "Cancel" translated into other language.  I read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901745/do-browsers-localize-the-ok-and-cancel-buttons-of-the-javascript-confirm-popup?rq=1 but this doesnt work for me.

Comment: Ah, I see, a browser-generated dialog ala `confirm` or `alert`.

Comment: Yes.  I am talking about confirm dialog which is from javascript.  In confirm box,  I always see the confirmation buttons in english instead of the browser language.

Comment: Worksforme. If I change the language setting of Chrome to German, I see "OK" and "Abbrechen". Where did you change it, did you restart Chrome?

Comment: yes, i did but still i see the confirmation buttons text in english..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to use `confirm()` and `alert()` JavaScript functions and have reliable results. It simply depends on the language of web browser, that is the **program**, not your preferred language.
The preferred language is used to tell the web server what is your preference in reference to the **web page** language.

So how to localize the confirmation or message dialogs, you would ask?
Well, get rid of them. Instead, please use [jQuery UI Dialog's modal confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) and follow your regular localization method for JavaScript string resources.
It is the only way to have confirmation dialog's titles and buttons translated reliably to the language of your web application.