# Javascript confirmation dialog in other language

Tags: javascript, dialog, multilingual

I wonder does javascript able to show other language in the confirmation box? by default of alert will show yes/no, can I change it to mandarin? your comment and suggestion is much appreaciated.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901745/do-browsers-localize-the-ok-and-cancel-buttons-of-the-javascript-confirm-popup

Comment: @Aiken what I want is does it possible to show in other language by default, not customizing any of it. :(

Comment: It states: "Firefox and Chrome are not using MessageBox so technically they should be following the browser UI language settings. Confirmed."

Comment: @Aiken so does any method will convert it to the language base on the computer culture info? dont care about yes or no or confirm. convert everything to the language that base on the culture info of the pc.